# Tensorflow loading weights on CPU when model is trained on GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp, tf.keras

I wrote a Bert model in Colab and I trained it using GPU and downloaded the weights for further inference. For prediction, I don't need GPU and I was testing on my local machine without GPU. But I was getting the following error while loading in my local PC, while there was no error on Colab. I'm not able to get how to proceed further.

```
File "/home/akash/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/load.py", line 909,
 in load_internal str(err) + "\n If trying to load on a different device from the "
FileNotFoundError: Op type not registered 'CaseFoldUTF8' in binary running on akash. Make sure
the Op and Kernel are registered in the binary running in this process.
Note that if you are loading a saved graph which used ops from tf.contrib, accessing (e.g.) 
`tf.contrib.resampler` should be done before importing the graph, as contrib ops are lazily registered 
when the module is first accessed.
```

I have loaded using,

```py
self.classifier_model = self.build_classifier_model()
self.classifier_model.load_weights(BERT_HEADING)
```

Output of `pip list | grep 'tensorflow'`

```
tensorflow                         2.5.0
tensorflow-addons                  0.13.0
tensorflow-datasets                4.3.0
tensorflow-estimator               2.5.0
tensorflow-hub                     0.12.0
tensorflow-metadata                1.1.0
tensorflow-model-optimization      0.6.0
tensorflow-text                    2.5.0
```

My model:

```py
bert_model_name = 'small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-8_H-512_A-8'
tfhub_handle_encoder = 'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-8_H-512_A-8/1'
tfhub_handle_preprocess = 'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_preprocess/3'
bert_preprocess_model = hub.KerasLayer(tfhub_handle_preprocess)
bert_model = hub.KerasLayer(tfhub_handle_encoder)

def build_classifier_model():
  text_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(), dtype=tf.string, name='text')
  preprocessing_layer = hub.KerasLayer(tfhub_handle_preprocess, name='preprocessing')
  encoder_inputs = preprocessing_layer(text_input)
  encoder = hub.KerasLayer(tfhub_handle_encoder, trainable=True, name='BERT_encoder')
  outputs = encoder(encoder_inputs)
  net = outputs['pooled_output']
  net = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(net)
  net = tf.keras.layers.Dense(updated_data_frame['heading'].nunique(), activation='softmax', name='classifier')(net)
  return tf.keras.Model(text_input, net)

classifier_model = build_classifier_model()

epochs = 5
steps_per_epoch = tf.data.experimental.cardinality(train_ds).numpy()
num_train_steps = steps_per_epoch * epochs
num_warmup_steps = int(0.1*num_train_steps)

init_lr = 3e-5
optimizer = optimization.create_optimizer(init_lr=init_lr,
                                          num_train_steps=num_train_steps,
                                          num_warmup_steps=num_warmup_steps,
                                          optimizer_type='adamw')
classifier_model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
                         loss=loss,
                         metrics=['CategoricalAccuracy'])
print(f'Training model with {tfhub_handle_encoder}')
history = classifier_model.fit(x=train_ds,
                               validation_data=val_ds,
                               epochs=5)

saved_model_path = 'resume_headings.h5'
classifier_model.save_weights(saved_model_path)

reloaded_model= build_classifier_model() # <-- This was working fine on Colab but giving an error (detailed desc above)
reloaded_model.load_weights(saved_model_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are having is mostly likely due to the fact you do not have locally installed `tensorflow-text` (or the environment in which you are using BERT does not have `tensorflow-text` installed).

I am making this observation because I can see you have both PIP and CONDA as package managers and it is easy to fall into trap (not knowing what environment/virtual environment you are using).

For example, you could have an environment with TF 2.3 and pandas 1.0.0 and another one with TF 2.5 and pandas 1.2.0. Now of course, if you use the second environment, you cannot use the functionalities that come with pandas versions > 1.0.0, because the dependencies are actually relative to that specific environment. I hope it became clearer to you.

Also please make sure that you have the exact same version of TensorFlow locally with the one that you trained your BERT model.

(Use `!pip install tensorflow-text` to install it)

You can also see a very similar error here: https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/issues/705

At the same time, if you want to ensure your model is loaded on the GPU, use this snippet/logic:

```
with tf.device('/GPU:0'):
    model = load_model()
```

Comment: I have already installed tensorflow-text in my local machine, I have also added the output of `pip list | grep 'tensorflow'` in the post above. And the colab I was using to train the model on GPU also had tensorflow-text installed and the same version. But I couldn't really understand what was  the problem there.. And I wanted lo load the weights on my CPU not GPU, I have tried different ways but none of them worked.

Comment: The load_model() appears to be pointing towards anaconda, not pip. It doesn't matter that you installed tensorflow-text with PIP if the Anaconda Environment from which you are trying to create the model doesn't "see-it". You can have multiple environments on your local machine, and it is very likely that in some environment you have, say TF 2.2.0 and in some other 2.5.0. Of course there are differences between them.

Comment: My suggestion is to create a virtual environment from scratch (not depending on Anaconda) and try redoing those steps (of course have all those dependencies that you need installed)

Comment: I tried installing all the packages in new venv, but still the same error persists except the trace has changed. Its now from `/home/akash/bert/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/load.py`

Comment: So every dependency has the same version like on Colab? (including the Python version?)

Comment: Yes all of them are same version as colab including python version